# intercept function calls going out of a function python

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I would like to intercept the function calls happening inside a function. This is aimed at producing a "mocking" sort of an effect on function calls inside a function.

For example:

```
def calls_add(a,b):
    print "this function calls add"
    c = add(a,b)
    print "call to add returned",c
```

I would like to add a decorator on top of call_add to intercept calls to the function add and call some other function instead (with the same arguments being passed to add)

Something like this:

```
def some_other_func(*args,**kwargs):
    return "test value"

@mock(add,some_other_func)
def calls_add(a,b):
    print "this function calls add"
    c = add(a,b)
    print "call to add returned",c
```

Is there a way to do this without having to touch the code of calls_add. I was looking at the inspect library but need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `unittest.mock.patch`:

> patch() acts as a function decorator, class decorator or a context manager. Inside the body of the function or with statement, the target is patched with a new object. When the function/with statement exits the patch is undone.

From the API [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) and documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#patch-decorators)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`mock.patch`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch). You have the following two posiblities:

1. If you want to use a decorator:

   ```
   import mock


   def some_other_func(*args, **kwargs):
       return "test value"


   def add(a, b): 
       return a + b 


   @mock.patch("__main__.add", some_other_func)
   def calls_add(a, b): 
       print "this function calls add"
       c = add(a, b)
       print "call to add returned", c


   calls_add(1, 2)
   ```
2. If you do not want to use a decorator:

   ```
   import mock


   def some_other_func(*args, **kwargs):
       return "test value"


   def add(a, b): 
       return a + b 


   def calls_add(a, b): 
       print "this function calls add"
       c = add(a, b)
       print "call to add returned", c


   calls_add(1, 2)

   with mock.patch("__main__.add", some_other_func):
       calls_add(1, 2)
   ```